# Getting "accessing beyond memory" error when it is tried to copy data from a pointer of type constant char *. Why?

Tags: c++, pointers, constants, memcpy

The following statement throws accessing beyond memory error. I am still not sure why it would do that. Can anyone please help me what I am doing wrong here? Thanks

```
    memcpy(mhp_ptr->dpair[0].dpairid, id0, 8);
```

Here **id0** is of type **const char ***

where, mhp_ptr is of type mhp_t * which is defined as follows:-

```
typedef struct mhp_s 
{ 
    uint8_t  editor[16];
    uint64_t refcode;
    uint64_t error_id;
    union
    {
        uint8_t dpairtbl[16][6];
        dpairtbl_t dpair[6];
    };
}  mhp_t;
```

and dpairtbl_t is defined as follows:-

```
typedef struct dpairtbl_s
{ 
    char  dpairid[8];
    uint64_t dpairdata;
} dpairtbl_t;
```

Error :-
        accessing beyond allocated memory
        'memcpy' could read 8 bytes from the buffer `id0'

Compiler setting I have for my project treats warnings as an error. Normal compilation works fine but it issues a warning which as per setting in my compiler is treated as error. **Was just wondering why it works fine for strcpy but issues a warning in case of memcpy. Is there any C++ restriction on usage of memcpy in case of strings**?

Comment: Well, how much memory is `id0` pointing at?

Comment: Your writing the size of 8 chars + an int64 into a memory containing 8 chars.

Comment: id0 is of type const char*. If I use strcpy it works fine, I get no error but if I use memcpy it throws an error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think of `memcpy` as copying of bytes in memory as they are:

```
memcpy(mhp_ptr->dpair[0].dpairid, id0, 8);
```

*If the length of `id0` is less than 8, `memcpy` will also copy memory that doesn't belong to you and if it is 8 or more characters long, `dpairid` will not be null-terminated correctly.*

In case you have no guarantees about the size of `id0` being exactly 8 bytes, you should treat it as string so that the length will be determined based on the terminating character:

```
strncpy (mhp_ptr->dpair[0].dpairid, id0, 7);
mhp_ptr->dpair[0].dpairid[7] = '\0';
```

Comment: Even if I use 8 instead of sizeof(dpairtbl_t) it throws an error, sorry edited the ques to avoid confusion

Comment: @user3480704: Show us how `id0` is defined and initialized.

Comment: @user3480704 then we're back to the question of what's in id0

Comment: id0 is defined as a const char * id0 as one of functional parameters. It basically contains string to provide error info.

Answer (score 0):

One potential problem is that you're copying into dpairid (which is of size 8) with the size dpairtbl_t (which is probably 16)

Either you have the wrong size (use sizeof(dpairid)) or perhaps

```
typedef struct dpairtbl_u
{ 
     char  dpairid[8];
     uint64_t dpairdata;
} dpairtbl_t;
```

should be a union

```
typedef union dpairtbl_u
{ 
     char  dpairid[8];
     uint64_t dpairdata;
} dpairtbl_t;
```

Comment: It is of type struct only, if I use strcpy it works fine but it throws an error in case of memcpy. Sorry for the confusion, edited the ques for further clarification

Comment: @user3480704 with strcpy it will work if id0's length is less than 8, because strcpy stops when it finds the '\0' at the end of the string.

Comment: yes exactly that why for any future string related operation, I was wondering if memcpy is the right way to go forward

Comment: If you can, use std::string... if you're stuck with char *, use strncpy (as @LihO indicated), the difference with strcpy is that it allows to specify a maximum number of characters to copie (so that you don't overrun the destination buffer).

Answer (score 0):

Besides the other answers, i didn't get any error and it worked. Here is my code:

```
const char* id0 = "stackoverflow question";
mhp_t* mhp_ptr = new mhp_t;

memcpy(mhp_ptr->dpair[0].dpairid, id0, sizeof(dpairtbl_t));

cout << mhp_ptr->dpair[0].dpairid << endl;

delete mhp_ptr;
```

The output is:

```
stackove
```

When i looked `sizeof(dpairtbl_t)` value, it is `8`. Maybe you have forgotten allocation/initialization of pointer `mhp_ptr`. And how do you initialize `id0`?

Comment: id0 is passed as a string. Normal compilation works fine but it issues a warning which as per setting in my compiler is treated as error. Was just wondering why it works fine for strcpy but issues a warning in case of memcpy. Is there any C++ restriction on it?